# Is there a way to get the responseType of an AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that needs to intercept XMLHttpRequests and responses. However, the responseType is often variable. Sometimes it's text, sometimes a JSON object, and others an arraybuffer or empty string.

Is there some way to get the responseType?

I've tried using responseType, but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried like this:

```
if (response.responseType == "text") {};
else if (response.responseType == "arraybuffer") {};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's present on the original xhr object (should be accessible as `event.target` or `this` in your interceptor), not on the response.

Comment: https://gomakethings.com/working-with-xhr-response-data-in-vanilla-js/